# Two to many relationship in ASP.Net MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF for the first time and I'm in trouble for setting up a two to many relation between 2 entities.

The 2 entities are 'Customer' and 'Order'.

A customer has many orders.
An order has two customers : an invoiced customer and a delivered customer.

Here is my models :

**Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le code client est obligatoire.")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La raison sociale est obligatoire.")]
    [StringLength(35, ErrorMessage = "La raison sociale ne peut excéder 35 caractères.")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsExported { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Order**

```
public class Order
{
    [Required]
    public  int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("InvoicedCustomer")]
    public int InvoicedCustomerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("DeliveredCustomer")]
    public int DeliveredCustomerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PaymentTermsID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OrderRef { get; set; }
    public bool IsExported { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer InvoicedCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer DeliveredCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentTerms PaymentTerms { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to create an Order and both InvoicedCustomer and DeliveredCustomer are set on the creation.

But I can't access Customer.Orders, I understand that the way I'm doing, EF think that an order belong to only one customer and this customer is not set on order creation.

I don't want to set a many-to-many relationship between those entities because an order has 2 customers only.

I'm looking for a way to access Customer.Orders in customer views, I can't figure how to do.

I've try this :

**In CustomerController**

```
var orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.InvoicedCustomer == customer
                                          || o.DeliveredCustomer == customer).ToList();
        customer.Orders = orders;
```

**In Views.Customer.Details**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Orders)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Référence</dt>
                <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderRef)</dd>
                <dt>Client facturé</dt>
                <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoicedCustomer.CompanyName)</dd>
                <dt>Client livré</dt>
                <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveredCustomer.CompanyName)</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
```

Unfortunetly this is not working.

Any idea to access orders of a customer, assuming that both InvoicedCustomer and DeliveredCustomer must have the order accessible ?

I hope my problem is well detailed.
Thank you !

Comment: You say this is not working? Are you getting an error or any exceptions or? This could be an issue with the fact you are specifying 2 foreign keys and EF may be getting confused, but I need to see the error to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Customer class Make 2 collections (two 1 to many relations) and add InversePropertyAttribute

```
[InverseProperty("InvoicedCustomer")]
public virtual ICollection<Order> InvoicedOrders { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("DeliveredCustomer")]
public virtual ICollection<Order> DeliveredOrders { get; set; }
```

If You need all products in one property add collection with notmapped attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Order> Orders => this.InvoicedOrders.Concat(this.DeliveredOrders);
```

Comment: Hi garret ! Is there a 2 step answer or 2 possible ways ? I think it's 2 possible ways but I'm not sure.

Comment: It was 2 step answer (where 2nd step was optional), I removed missleading numbers.